# why is this switch case not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

why is this switch case not working... even if i pick the button monday it shows me default message..

```
switch (finalsave.weekday) {
    case finalsave.weekday == 1:
    trace ("monday");
    break;

    case finalsave.weekday== 2:
    trace ("tuesday");
    break;

    case finalsave.weekday == 3:
    trace ("wednesday");
    break;

    case finalsave.weekday == 4:
    trace ("thursday");
    break;

    case finalsave.weekday == 5:
    trace ("friday");
    break;

    default:
    trace ("nothingness");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to ditch that godawful switch-case altogether:

```
var weekdays: Array = [
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
]

var index : int = finalsave.weekday -1;
trace( weekdays[ index ] );
```

Comment: lol thx... I want to learn more about arrays before kinda using them... I tried learning it but it didn't make too much sense... can u give me a hand... forexample I established these 7 vairables...and one of it gets assigned a value when it's pressed how would I do that?

Comment: I posted a question could u answer there please lol? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589128/need-some-array-help-in-actionscript-3

Answer (score 3):

```
switch (finalsave.weekday) {
    case 1:
    trace ("monday");
    break;

    case 2:
    trace ("tuesday");
    break;

    case 3:
    trace ("wednesday");
    break;

    ... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After case, you should mention the possible value of your variable, 
Below is the syntax of switch case for action script, c/c++ , java and javascript:

Switch case using strings.
view sourceprint?

```
switch("hello world")
{
case "hello":
trace("The man says hello");
break;

case "hello cat":
trace("The man says hello cat");
break;

case "hello world":
trace("The man says hello world");
break;

default:
trace("None of the above were met");
}
```

In this example the text "The man says hello world" is traced out.
Switch Case using integers, what fun.

```
switch(1)
{
case 1:
trace("The Number 1");
break;

case 2:

case 3:
trace("The Number 2 or 3");
break;

default:
trace("None of the numbers above");
}
```

from http://www.how-to-code.com/as3-actionscript3/as3-conditionals/as3-switch-case.html